# What's the probability of only one of the two students pass the test?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Ann and Ben will take a test next week. Ann has a probability of 4/5 passing while Ben has a probability of 1/3 of passing the test.

1. What's the probability of both of them pass the test?
2. What's the probability of only one of them pass the test?

I think the two students passing the test are independent events. The answer for question 1 would be 4/5 times 1/3 which gives us 4/15, right?

What would be the answer for the second question? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let P(A) represent probability Ann pass the test while P(A') be Ann failing the test.
You are correct for the first one. It is indeed 4/15.
For second one you need to find $P(A)*P(B') + P(A')*P(B)$ which is basically one of them passing while the other fails. (It equals 3/5)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that Bob is not looking over Ann's shoulder.1. You are right. 2. Pr(exactly one passes)=Pr(Ann passes&Bob fails ) + PR(Ann fails& Bob passes)=$$\frac{4}{5} \times\frac{2}{3} +\frac{1}{5}\times \frac{1}{3}=\frac{9}{15}$$$$=\frac{3}{5}$$